# why is else statement executing?

Tags: python

I am going through the cs50 intro to python course and currently trying to complete one of the problems in the problem set. I will show my code below.

```
file_type = input('File name: ').lower().strip()
if file_type.endswith('.jpg'):
    print('image/jpeg')
elif file_type.endswith('.jpeg'):
    print('image/jpeg')
elif file_type.endswith('.gif'):
    print('image/gif')
elif file_type.endswith('.png'):
    print('image/png')
if file_type.endswith('.pdf'):
    print('application/pdf')
elif file_type.endswith('.zip'):
    print('application/zip')
if file_type.endswith('.txt'):
    print('text/plain')
else:
    print('application/octet-stream')
```

the output for some reason is printing the else statement with the if or elif statements that have come back as true. so why would the else statement execute if the statements prior are true?? please help, I am banging my head against the wall over this.

Comment: change all your `if XXX` except the first one to `elif` as an `if` starts a new if/elif/else block that will also process anything from the earlier if/else blocks

Comment: you have three `if` statements.   change the '.pdf' and '.txt' statements to `elif`

Comment: thanks for the helps guys, it worked. still new to this but I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

try to use if...elif...else structure

````
if file_type.endswith('.jpg'):
    print('image/jpeg')
elif file_type.endswith('.jpeg'):
    print('image/jpeg')
elif file_type.endswith('.gif'):
    print('image/gif')
elif file_type.endswith('.png'):
    print('image/png')
elif file_type.endswith('.pdf'):
    print('application/pdf')
elif file_type.endswith('.zip'):
    print('application/zip')
elif file_type.endswith('.txt'):
    print('text/plain')
else:
    print('application/octet-stream')```
````

Comment: Yes that worked! thanks a lot. I'm still new to this so I'm sorry if I was asking a foolish question! At least i know from now on.